# Signed and unsigned `rep` in `std::chrono` clocks

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono

The `rep` type of `std::chrono::system_clock` is required to be a signed arithmetic type, whereas `steady_clock` and `high_resolution_clock` (and custom clock types) are not required to have a signed `rep` type.

What is the rationale for this distinction, and what would be the consequences of a clock using an unsigned `rep` type?

Comment: C++17 notes: "Requires: system_clock::duration::min() < system_clock::duration::zero() shall be true. [Note: This implies that rep is a signed type. —end note ]" At a guess that allows you to construct time points before the start of the epoch. With most implementations that means before 1970.

Comment: "Requires" was changed to "Remarks" as per this document: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0411r0.html

Comment: @P.W: Thanks, interesting. I quoted from N4659, dated 2017-03-21. I believe that was the final draft of C++17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rationale was to allow vendors a little more freedom for `steady_clock` and `high_resolution_clock`.  In hindsight, that freedom wasn't necessary as all implementations to date use signed integral types.

The consequences of using an unsigned `rep` in these clocks is that their `duration` nested type would not be one of the six "predefined" durations:

```
nanoseconds
microseconds
milliseconds
seconds
minutes
hours
```

As these are required to be signed.  Also clients of a clock using an unsigned `rep` would have to be careful about subtracting `time_point`s from that clock:  subtracting `t0 - t1` when `t0 < t1` would result in an unsigned overflow value:  Well defined, but potentially unexpected.

Such a clock can be used safely, and there do exist use cases for the unsigned overflow.  But it would likely be more error prone in general.

The reason this latitude was not extended to `system_clock` was that it was hoped that `system_clock` would track [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), and I wanted to require that datetimes prior to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC be representable in `system_clock::time_point`.  `system_clock` is the one clock that is required to be relatable to human calendars.

In the draft C++20 spec, the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) relationship will finally be specified, and it will be much easier to convert between `system_clock::time_point` and the civil calendar, including datetimes prior to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

But `steady_clock` remains a "stopwatch":  Very good for timing things, but no relationship whatsoever to human calendars.